# какой паттерн использовать для сохранения и загрузки данных( в память устройства)

Tags: java, android

Наверняка есть какой то общий шаблон или достаточно создать класс и в нем пару статических методов для сохранения данных  и загрузки ?

*UPD* 
 что скажете насчет паттерна Memento? это то что нужно? он вроде бы нарушает в чем то ООП.

Comment: что вы хотите загружать? Если это объект то определите в нем метод, который будет загружать и сохранять объект в полученных потоках. Если это просто набор данных, оберните их в объект и напишите ему методы.

Comment: ну это данные, json, которые приходят с класса занимающегося загрузкой по сети. Не создавать ли мне для одной строки целый объект. Я пока что создал класс который на вход принимает строку и записывает его или же наоборот загружает  в строку сохраненные данные.

Comment: Простой я думал есть какой то общий случай для всех типов загрузок. Будь то изображение полученное по сети или полученное скриншотом, данные которые не имеют своего класса , в котором реализованы методы для работы с этими данными. Я решил просто создать класс который на вход принимает требуемый тип данных и записывает. Но методам делающим запись  практически без разницы какой тип данных записывать, поэтому возможно существует какой то общий шаблон.

Comment: ну общий случай есть In(Out)putStream. Пишет и читает байты, т.к. вся информация в байтах и вам не хочется использовать DTO то так.